# How to route to a ionic tab with route-outlet?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How do I route to a ion-tab with a router-outlet?
What do I write in the login.page.ts in the goNext function?
I tried: 
`this.router.navigate(['/profile']);` and `this.router.navigate(['/(profile:profile)']);`

and how do you route it within html?

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { RootComponent } from './root/root.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: RootComponent, children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'chat', loadChildren: './chat-list/chat-list.module#ChatListPageModule', outlet: 'chat' },
  ] },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomePageModule' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

root.component.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab label="Profiel" icon="people">
    <ion-router-outlet name="profile"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="Vragen" icon="musical-note">
    <ion-router-outlet name="question"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab label="Chat" icon="person">
    <ion-router-outlet name="chat"></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

login.page.ts

```
goNext() {
      this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { profile: ['profile(profile:profile)'] } }]);
  }
```

Comment: I don't know about how ionic works but according to your question in angular you can route to auxiliary route from template like `<li><a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { profile: ['profile'] } }]">Go</a></li>`

Comment: I have made this work: this.router.navigate(['/tabs', { outlets: { 'chat' : 'chat' }}]); but why doesn't this work with routerLink? I get this error: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs'

Comment: nvm it's working now I had to enclose routerLink with square brackets.